# Animated GIF in tcl/tk button widget

Tags: button, tcl, gif, tk-toolkit, animated-gif

I have a Tcl/tk application where user had to be notified from 10 days earlier of license expire. I want to implement a animated warning image in a button in right corner of toolbar to notify the same. Is there any methods to implement it? 
If it can not be done in a button, can this be possible as normal image or by other way. Any links or guidance is highly appreciable.

N.B. the animated image can be some thing like this [image]

Comment: Do you just want to have an animated gif or have it specifically in a button? In a label, you can use something like [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4882). In a button, I guess you would instead re-`configure` the button's picture at set intervals of time to give that illusion of animation

Answer (score 0):

For the software I was writing the general solution was to re-`configure` the image on the label at a set time interval. For instance,

```
global toggle;
set toggle 0;
while {!{some condition to make the image stop changing}} {
   after 3000 {
      if {$toggle == 0} {
         set toggle 1;
         myLabel configure -image onImage;
      } else {
         set toggle 0;
         myLabel configure -image offImage;
      }
   }
   vwait toggle;
}
```

Use `after` to make the delay between the toggling of the image, and use `vwait` to stop the loop from continuing until the image has toggled, thereby forcing it to wait `3000` ms, or 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got a multi-frame GIF already, your easiest technique for dealing with it is to regularly reconfigure which frame of the GIF is displayed in the image. This will then be reflected in your GUI. Here's how to swap between the first two frames every half second.

```
proc swapFramesEveryHalfSecond {image {index 0}} {
    $image configure -format "gif -index $index"
    # Arrange for us to be called again in 500 milliseconds to select the other frame
    set nextIndex [expr {1 - $index}]
    after 500 swapFramesEveryHalfSecond $image $nextIndex
}
swapFramesEveryHalfSecond $yourImage
```

The rest of your GUI just needs to use that photo image (and keep the event loop serviced, as normal for any Tk GUI).

Comment: Note that the above 'loops' between the first two frames only. If the animation has more frames, `nextIndex` will have to be handled slightly differently.